# Selecting one among many possible choices in a Web page using Java

Tags: java, html

I want to get the HTML code of the following Web Page (http://www.studenti.ict.uniba.it/esse3/ListaAppelliOfferta.do) after:

1. selecting "Dipartimento di Informatica" among Facoltà
2. selecting "Informatica" (or one of the others available)
3. clicking "Avvia Ricerca"

I am not very keen in the matter but I noticed the URL of the page stays the same after each selection!?!

Can anyone help describing, possibly in details, how can I do that? Unfortunately I am not expert in web programming.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tests, it refresh the pages with a POST request

```
fac_id:1012 --
cds_id:197  -- 
ad_id: -- Attività didattica
docente_id:  -- Id of the docent selected
data:06/03/2014 -- Date
```

Anyway you missed the value of `Attività ditattica`, `Docente` and `Data esame`

Just run a HTTP request using [`HttpURLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) (?) with this POST args, and with a XML parser read the output of tplmessage table.

Try this tutorial for HTTP request: [click](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-use-httpurlconnection-post-data-to-web-server/139).

Try to read this to understand how to parse response: [click](http://theoryapp.com/parse-xml-using-dom-in-java/)

---

An example using the code of the tutorial:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
try
{
    URL url = new URL("http://www.studenti.ict.uniba.it/esse3/ListaAppelliOfferta.do");
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // open the connection with the url

    String params =
            "fac_id=1012&cds_id=197"; // You need to add ad_id, docente_id and data

    connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); // i need to use POST request method
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(params.getBytes().length)); // It will add the length of params

    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "it-IT"); // language italian

    connection.setUseCaches (false);
    connection.setDoInput   (true);
    connection.setDoOutput  (true);

    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
            connection.getOutputStream ());
    wr.writeBytes (params); // pass params
    wr.flush (); // send request
    wr.close ();

    //Get Response
    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line;
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(line);
        response.append('\r');
    }
    rd.close();
}
catch (MalformedURLException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
    // close connection if created
    if (connection != null)
        connection.disconnect();
}
```

In `response` you will have the DOM of the page.

---

Anyway, use Chrome developers tool to get request args:

[image: aw]

Comment: Thanks Marco, your help has been greatly useful. I managed to obtain the HTML code of the page containing the table I needed simply modifying a little the params of the POST request. 

For example

    String params = "fac_id=1012&cds_id=1102&ad_id=&docente_id=&data=&btnSubmit=Avvia Ricerca";

Allows to obtain the table containing all the infos about the exams of Corso di Studio = 1102.

I did not add any ad_id, data or docente_id because I am interested in obtaining all the exams.

The btn=Submit=Avvia Ricerca did the rest for having those data displayed in the table on the Web page.